# Swift 4 Correct way of disabling a UIButton in UITableViewCell

Tags: swift, uitableview, uibutton, didselectrowatindexpath

I need to know how to correctly disable a button in a TableViewCell in a way that the cell wouldn't get selected if the disabled button area is touched? Right now I can see the disabled button so if user try to touch the button which is grayed out the row gets selected instead of nothing happening! I have looked a lot but the net is full of unrelated answered about disabling buttons and non of them talk about the issue with tableviewcells.

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with disabling a button (which you appear to be doing already). Your question should be about how to prevent a row from being selected. You need to provide a lot more details in your question. How is a button enabled/disabled in your cell? What does your data model look like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the button doesn't receive any touch events anymore once you disabled it, a solution might be to not actually disable the button but to fake it instead.

You could create a variable to maintain the state of your button:

```
var isEnabled: Bool = true {
    didSet {
        if !isEnabled {
            button.setTitleColor(UIColor.gray, forState: .normal)
        } else {
            //Set the color back to the original value
            button.setTitleColor(UIColor.black, forState: .normal)
        }
    }
}
```

This will gray out the buttons title whenever isEnabled is set to false.

Then, in your action method, you insert a line for an early return at the beginning:

```
func buttonClicked(sender: UIButton) {
    if !isEnabled {
        return
    }
    // Otherwise, handle click event
}
```

This way, the button eats the click but doesn't do anything when it is disabled and therefore, the cell shouldn't get selected.

Comment: @ Ahmad F : Thanks for reminding, I just did

Comment: @ Lukas : Thanks a lot, this was exactly what I was looking for, works just like what I wanted.